# Is there a way to share a Excel VB Macro as a tool for all future workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a VB script that re-formats data exported to excel from a website so that it is compatible with a geocoder. As of now every export I have to go in, past the VB code run it and save the changes. I am wondering if there is a way to make the VB code available as a tool for all workbooks so it is just a matter of opening the xls file clicking a button and saving it?

Comment: Add the macro to your personal workbook or make an xlam add-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a little on BigBen's comment:

Open the Excel file with your code in. Open a new blank Workbook. Open up the VBA Editor (Alt-F11).

Drag the module which contains your code to the new workbook (in the left-hand navigator pane). You should see it add to this new Workbook.

Save you new workbook as MyFunctions (or whatever name you fancy) but choose the "Excel Add-in (*.xlam)" file type. You should see a new file appear in your folder as MyFunctions.xlam.

Back in Excel, from the File menu, choose Options (right at the bottom). And then Add-Ins from the left-hand list. At the bottom will be a drop-down box "Manage: Excel Add Ins". Hit Go...

You'll a list of the add-ins that your Excel knows about: some will be checked (that is they will be loaded at start-up) and some not.

Choose Browse, and navigate to wherever you saved MyFunctions.xlam. And double click on it. You may get a security warning (as your addin doesnt have a digital signature) but just go ahead and enable it (as you wrote the code: this is not blanket advice!). Close Excel (this remembers your choices).

When you next open Excel you should see your add-in file open in the VBA Editor, and your macros and UDFs available in whatever worksheet you are using.

Comment: I ended up using this, https://trumpexcel.com/excel-add-in/ I think it is close to what you are outlining. The link goes a step further in to adding it to a tool bar. I didn't see your response until I came back to post the link as the solution. This question was asked but the solution I think was for an older version of excel; I couldn't follow it anyhow.